Passing artifacts between pipelines
The DependantPipeline (which is triggered by the another pipeline: MainPipeline) causes errors on Azure DevOps:

Download Pipeline artifact
Starting: Download Pipeline artifact
Download from the specified build: #178678
Download artifact to: /agent/_work/64/Pipeline
##[error]Artifact Pipeline was not found for build 178678.
Finishing: Download Pipeline artifact

I tried to trace the file which is responsible to download artifacts in my repo, however by title I cant find it Download Pipeline artifact. Does it mean someone does not use displayName parameter and it takes that by default? Or would you give me any hint how to navigate/track files based on the output from Azure DevOps? So far by the the name works for me, not this time.
However, I found those files, which seems to be related with publishing/downloading, I hope:
take_templates.yml
steps:
  - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
    displayName: "Templates from DEV"
    inputs:
      artifact: "Pipelines"
      buildType: "current"
      targetPath: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/Pipelines"

deployment.yml
parameters:
  - name: pipelineOptions
    type: object
  - name: environment
    type: string

jobs:
  - deployment: Initializing
    displayName: "Initializing"
    environment: ${{parameters.environment}}
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - template: take_templates.yml
            - ${{ if eq(parameters.pipelineOptions.isDetectChangesEnabled, 'true') }}:
              - template: ./take_changes.yml

take_changes.yml
steps:
  - download: current
    displayName: "DetectChanges"
    artifact: DetectChanges
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: "Publish Changes"
    name: "DetectChanges"
    inputs:
      targetType: "FilePath"
      filePath: take_changes.ps1
      arguments: -inputFileName './changes.json'

Currently, I have a pipeline (MainPipeline) which triggers another one (DependantPipeline), which in turns should make a deployment based on the changes, and take (as I believe) uploaded artifacts in the previous pipeline: MainPipeline, to the triggered pipeline: DependantPipeline.
EDIT 1.
I tried different combinations to stick this together based on the articles, however no no no I cant complete this
Dependant pipeline definition:
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: Pipelines
      type: git
      name: Pipelines
      ref: test/pipeline
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: SourcePipeline
      project: DEV
      source: 'dev-main'
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
                - test/pipeline
# the rest of code goes here


Hi Kreg, Good day to you and again appreciate your sharing. With the help of @Rui, we could see - download: current # refers to artifacts published by current pipeline; however, your downstream dependent pipeline itself probably didn't published any artifacts. For this, we can opt to - download: <main pipeline resource identifier> to download the artifacts published by the upstream pipeline added in the resources node of the dependent pipeline YAML definition, which also triggers the dependent pipeline.

See another document on pipeline resources and artifacts download for more information. Kindly let us know if the suggestion works for you. Thank you for the time for update and all the efforts.

I tried, however without success, still I see errors on Azure DevOps. I paste the definitions for Main and Dependent Pipelines, if you could check.

Hi @Kreg, Can you please remove all those irrelevant templates from the original post just keep your update? It is so hard to find which template includes the - download step. Is it in the deploy.yml? We don't see any steps in it.

In deploy.yml I see only diffrent stages based on target deployment, like DEV, PRD etc. I cut it only to DEV section. I assume that some of those yml from main question might cause that issue, since I tried to search all records by word download. Thats why I picked all of those yml with word download with hope it might be informative. Sorry, if I messed, let me know. I wiped it out a bit.

Appreciate your taking time to share the update. Please find my findings in the answer blow. It seemed that neither the DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 or download updated had incurred this error. Hope the information may help you locate the affected step.

Based on the update where additional YAML templates were shared, we could see

The DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 pipeline task with the displayName: "Download Templates from DEV" in take_templates.yml was defined to download the artifacts called Pipelines, which should be published during the current build due to buildType: "current", so that it could be consumed;
Another download pipeline task with NO displayName property in take_changes.yml was defined to download the artifacts called DetectChanges, which should be also published during the current build due to download: current;

However, neither of the two tasks seemed to incur this error, as the message ##[error]Artifact Pipeline was not found indicated that it was downloading artifacts called Pipeline, NOT Pipelines or DetectChanges.
For this, I am afraid you will need to check if there was any other DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 or download task that was defined to consume the artifacts called Pipeline without a displayName, which should be the one affected.

In addition, we did notice the PublishPipelineArtifact@0 task in init.yml published the artifacts called Pipelines. Let's assume init.yml was from the MainPipeline (dev-main), and you would expect to download the artifacts Pipelines during the downstream DependentPipeline.
If that was the case, the DependentPipeline should not use DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 buildType: "current" but use download: SourcePipeline instead. (SourcePipeline was the symbolic name of your pipeline resource dev-main as defined in your Dependent pipeline definition).
# Dependent pipeline definition

trigger: none

resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: SourcePipeline
      project: DEV
      source: 'dev-main'
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - test/pipeline

steps:
  # - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  #   displayName: "Download Templates from DEV"
  #   inputs:
  #     artifact: "Pipelines"
  #     buildType: "current"
  #     targetPath: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/Pipelines"

  - download: SourcePipeline
    artifact: "Pipelines"
    displayName: "Download Templates from DEV"


OK, I got confirmation to rebuild those ingestion template at our own taste. It is too much ingested yml, it hard to read. Thats why so far thank you for your support, I will try  to do that, or maybe you cold support me in this?  That download step which you suggest is going to be my new path to resolve that :) without any templates etc.
However that solution above does not work, the SourcePipeline correctly triggers the DependantPipeline, however that one shows on Azure DevOpsConfiguring the trigger failed, edit and save the pipeline againI appreciate your support  I mark it as complete

When using DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 or download tasks, the value current refers to artifacts that were published in the current pipeline, i.e. the same pipeline where these tasks are being used.
Given that your artifacts are coming from MainPipeline pipeline, you need to use different settings when using these tasks.
Example
Consider the following pipeline resource that generates an artifact named drop:
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: MainPipeline
    project: my-project
    source: my-source
    trigger: true

You can download the drop artifact as follows:
steps:
  - download: MainPipeline # as defined in the resources section
    artifact: drop # as defined in the source pipeline
    displayName: Download artifact

  # Artifacts from the associated pipeline resource are downloaded to 
  # $(Pipeline.Workspace)/<pipeline resource identifier>/<artifact name>.
  - script: |
      ls -la
    displayName: List files in artifact directory
    workingDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/MainPipeline/drop

Recommended reading

Publish and download pipeline artifacts
DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 - Download Pipeline Artifacts v2 task
steps.download definition

